# Component not changing after state change (componentDidMount fetch) - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making an news app following a tutorial I'm fetching data from newapi my code looks same as tutorial but my component does not change after I update the state (this.state.articles) I'm using setState function i tried console logging the state it looks fine after the state is updated render methods runs but it does not change anything what could be worng

my code/component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import NewsItem from './NewsItem'

export default class News extends Component {
    articles = [
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "espn-cric-info",
                "name": "ESPN Cric Info"
            },
            "author": null,
            "title": "PCB hands Umar Akmal three-year ban from all cricket | ESPNcricinfo.com",
            "description": "Penalty after the batsman pleaded guilty to not reporting corrupt approaches | ESPNcricinfo.com",
            "url": "http://www.espncricinfo.com/story/_/id/29103103/pcb-hands-umar-akmal-three-year-ban-all-cricket",
            "urlToImage": "https://a4.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=%2Fi%2Fcricket%2Fcricinfo%2F1099495_800x450.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2020-04-27T11:41:47Z",
            "content": "Umar Akmal's troubled cricket career has hit its biggest roadblock yet, with the PCB handing him a ban from all representative cricket for three years after he pleaded guilty of failing to report det… [+1506 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "espn-cric-info",
                "name": "ESPN Cric Info"
            },
            "author": null,
            "title": "What we learned from watching the 1992 World Cup final in full again | ESPNcricinfo.com",
            "description": "Wides, lbw calls, swing - plenty of things were different in white-ball cricket back then | ESPNcricinfo.com",
            "url": "http://www.espncricinfo.com/story/_/id/28970907/learned-watching-1992-world-cup-final-full-again",
            "urlToImage": "https://a4.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=%2Fi%2Fcricket%2Fcricinfo%2F1219926_1296x729.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2020-03-30T15:26:05Z",
            "content": "Last week, we at ESPNcricinfo did something we have been thinking of doing for eight years now: pretend-live ball-by-ball commentary for a classic cricket match. We knew the result, yes, but we tried… [+6823 chars]"
        }
    ]

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            articles: this.articles,
            loading: false
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const URL = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey="
        let data = await fetch(URL);
        let parsedData = await data.json()
        this.setState({
            articles: parsedData.articles
        })
        console.log(this.state.articles)
    }
    render() {
        console.log("render")
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="container">
                    <h2 className='my-4 mx-4'> NewsMonkey - Top Headlines </h2>
                    <div className="row">
                        {this.articles.map((elem) => {
                            return <div className="col-md-4" key={elem.url}>
                                <NewsItem title={elem.title?elem.title.slice(42):""} desc={elem.description?elem.description.slice(0, 88): ""} url={elem.url} imgURL={elem.urlToImage} />
                            </div>
                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not mapping through `this.state.articles` but `this.articles`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.articles` and `this.state.articles` are not the same.

You have a static property `this.articles` that you are using in the render logic - `this.articles.map(...`. Your fetch is updating state (like it should be).

Update your render to read from `this.state.articles` and it should work.

Comment: it works like a charm thanks you sir! i was praying for it to be a stupid problem thank God

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Curious Your code is correct

you just need to pay attention when making the `map`

you are using `this.articles` which is a fixed (mock) list

you need to call `map` in `this.state.articles` because this is the state you change in didMount